# How to send push notification crome android mobile device pwa

Tags: javascript, html, css, manifest, service-worker

I am making push notification is working fine desktop. but it is not showing on mobile device.why? how we can send push notification on crome android devices pwa(web app)

Comment: Does the installing itself work, when you do it manually over the menu? Because the banner shows only on the exactfirst or  second time you visited the site and that count is really hard to reset

Comment: Have you check your PWA criteria with Chrome Lighthouse?

Comment: seems to be working mate...I tried it on a Pixel 2 and I saw the banner pop up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The criteria are mentioned on this page (for chrome) : https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/app-install-banners/#criteria

Comment: I answered at the moment.